Automated LaTex document generated from Excel spreadsheet
Following on this conversation: Automatic LaTex document generation from Excel spreadsheet
Here is my mini example:

I'm trying to create an overview for 'Test' since I've expected them to order.
CommandButton1 should give me a pdf with the last two orders listed.
I can open a .tex file using
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ("C:\Path\input.tex")

However, how do I fill my .tex file with the data plus how to I run the code within VBA?
(not so concerned of how it looks, I can figure that out)
So, I manually transferred data to .tex:
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

\newcommand{\company} {Test} 

\begin{document}

Overdue: \company. \par

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l l c }
 (F2) Nov-23 & (E2) May-24 & (G2) expected: Nov-24 \\ 
 (F3) 1549 & (E3) 1714 & \\ 
(F4) 12 & (E4) 12 & \\  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\end{document}

How do I import the data above not manually?
